# SQLDataReader how to check for null column values?

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, sqlclient

I am using a SQLDataReader to insert column data into a string[].

However, some of the column values are null. I am a little unsure how to check for this because when I do reader[column_pos] it says the value is "n/a".

What check can I perform so that I could do something like:

```
for(int i=0; i<myarray.Length;i++){
    if(something){
        myarray[i] = reader[i];
    }
    else
    {
        myarray[i] = "";
    }
}
```

and insert a blank sting whenver there is a null in the column.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [IsDBNull](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.isdbnull.aspx)

```
for(int i=0; i<myarray.Length;i++){
    if(reader.IsDBNull(i)){
        myarray[i] = "";
    }
    else
    {
        myarray[i] = reader[i];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `if (reader[0] == DBNull.Value)`. If you have control over the queries run, you can alternatively use the SQL `ISNULL(field, default_value)` function to ensure the column returns a value.

For C# you may also use the if/else shorthand:

```
myArray[i] = (reader[i] == DBNull.Value) ? "" : reader[0];
```

Which translates to: If the reader value is `DBNULL`, use `""`, else use the reader value.

Answer (score 0):

[SqlDataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) class has the [IsDBNull](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.isdbnull.aspx) property.

You can write code as follow:

```
for(int i=0; i<myarray.Length;i++){
    if(myReader.IsDBNull(i)){
        myarray[i] = "";
    }
    else
    {
        myarray[i] = reader[i];

    } }
```

or better yet:

```
for(int i=0; i<myarray.Length;i++){
      myarray[i] = reader.IsDBNull(i) ? "" : reader[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myarray[i] = reader.IsDBNull(i) || reader[i] == DBNull.Value ? string.Empty : reader[i];
```